# Android Listview getting repeated elements on scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using listview in android application.
I have to download different images from web and add them under each list element.
Image downloading, saving to SD card for future reference and displaying is working as expected.

But as I try to scroll list, some images of first few elements get copied or moved to last elements.

This is very odd behaviour which I never came accross till now.

Please help me if some one got this same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: listview recycles views. You may be facing problem becoz of that

Comment: You have problems in your adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to implement recycling on your ListView adapter.. Here is a sample of Listview adapter that has recycling:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsDto> {
    private final Context context;
    ArrayList<NewsDto> nList;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsDto> nList) {
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_news_item, nList);
        this.context = context;
        this nList = nList;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView description;
        ImageView image1

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.description = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.news_description);
            holder.image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_image1);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
    // get a single data from your list.
    NewsDto newsDto= nlist.get(position);

    //initialization of Image
    holder.image1.setImageBitmap(newsDto.getImage());

        return view;

    }

}
```

It makes use of a class to save tags of every items in the listview when scrolling. So that your initializations will be recycled when you scroll back to a specific item that is already initialized.

Comment: How can we to add images dynamically in one of adapter element without disturbing others?
Is it possible to add views dynamically in adapter element ?

Comment: What do you mean add image dynamically?..The image in a single item changes from time to time?..if that so be sure to put all your algorithm before the view.setTag

Comment: I am having Layout in every list adapter element. One thread will keep on downloading images from web and keep on adding to layout one after another.
Downloading works, placement works. But as I scroll listview images get moved to other list adapter elemnets.

Comment: Well have you tried using this approach?..I think this should fix your problem..If not..Try to put the algorithm of changing of images in a single element before the vew.setTag

Answer (score 2):

Make `convertView = null` at the starting of the `getView()` method. i.e.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
               // your code
            }else{
               holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // your code
      }
```

This will stop recycling of `ListView` Elements. Its worked for me when I'm loading too many items and scrolling the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ViewHolder` pattern and keeping into account that Android recycles view, your adapter's `getView` would look like this (more pseudo-code):

```
public View getView(ViewGroup parent, View convertView, int position) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(...);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        // initialize view holder views from inflated convertView
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    // update each ViewHolder's View with relevant information
    return convertView;
}
```

For more details on how this mechanism works, have a look at this popular [Google IO presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) (it's from 2010)